# Add JSON keys/values while creating another JSON PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to pass some JSON keys/values that I have to another JSON I am creating dynamically.

For example, this is the JSON I have in `$json_create`

```
{
"Key 1":"Value 1",
"Key 2":"Value 2",
"Key 3":"Value 3",
"Key 4":"Value 4"
}
```

**That comes over** `file_get_contents`

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json_create= json_decode($requestBody);
```

**And this is the JSON I am creating**

```
$final_json = [
       $json_create,
       "type" => "message",
       "elements" => $json_merge,  
       "actions" => $actions_json
  ];

echo json_encode($final_json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

**Which print something like**

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "elements": [
    {
      "msg_text": "This is a simple response message"
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I am trying to achieve is**

```
{
    "Key 1":"Value 1",
    "Key 2":"Value 2",
    "Key 3":"Value 3",
    "Key 4":"Value 4",
    "type": "message",
    "elements": [
        {
          "msg_text": "This is a simple response message"
     }
   ]
 }
```

There is quite a lot on that subject but somehow I could not succeed in implementing it.

Comment: Use `json_decode($requestBody, true);` to get an array - you are currently getting an object back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$json_create = '{"Key1": "Value 1", "Key2": "Value 2", "Key3": "Value 3", "Key4": "Value 4"}';
$json_create = (array) json_decode($json_create);

$your_array = [
  "type" => "message",
  "elements" => 'foo',
  "actions" => 'bar'
];

$final_json = array_merge($json_create, $your_array);

$result = json_encode($final_json);


echo $result;
```

**output**

```
{
  Key1: "Value 1",
  Key2: "Value 2",
  Key3: "Value 3",
  Key4: "Value 4",
  type: "message",
  elements: "foo",
  actions: "bar"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Biswajit, that did the trick. Particularly the (array) portion `$json_create = (array) json_decode($json_create);`

Comment: that's called type casting

Comment: Give a second argument `true` to `json_decode`, then it returns an associative array instead of object.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_merge` rather than putting the `$json_create` inside the array.

```
$final_json = array_merge($json_create, 
    [
        "type" => "message",
        "elements" => $json_merge,  
        "actions" => $actions_json
    ]);
```

Comment: I am getting bull if I try to merge.

Comment: You mean getting null?

Comment: Yes, sorry typo... NULL

Comment: That sounds like `json_encode()` is getting an error. What does `json_last_error_message()` return?

Comment: A common reason for that is a character that can't be encoded properly.

Comment: it turned out that I should use (array) json_decode as suggested by Biswajit. Thanks for your help too.

Comment: json_decode without second parameter returns an object, this is probably the reason - I'm too lazy to test it right now :)

Comment: @lStoilov You should use `json_decode($requestBody, true)`

Comment: @Barmar, I have tested it with true but it didn't work either. The only case in which it worked was when adding (array).

Comment: That's impossible, they should do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using union operator also.

```
$requestBody = '{
    "Key 1":"Value 1",
    "Key 2":"Value 2",
    "Key 3":"Value 3",
    "Key 4":"Value 4"
    }';
$json_create= json_decode($requestBody, true );
$other_array = [
    "type" => "message",
    "elements" => [],  
    "actions" => []
];
$final_json = $json_create + $other_array;
```